# Using custom vimrc on mac causes syntax highlighting to be lost

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard, macos-sierra, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am using Vim 8.0 (in the Terminal), compiled by Homebrew, on Mac OS 10.12.6. I am trying to enable copy to clipboard (and paste from clipboard) using the usual yank/put commands. I've actually succeeded in doing this (following various online guides) by creating a .vimrc file in my home directory and adding the single line `set clipboard=unnamed`. However, this has had the undesired side effect of preventing the nice extension-specific syntax highlighting (that was enabled by default with the installation) from being loaded when vim opens (for example, when I open a .py file the text is now all white). Is there some way of enabling copy to clipboard without destroying the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Hi @paul, I believe you need `syntax enable` somewhere in your `.vimrc`. Have you got that? If not, can you paste your config so I can help you troubleshoot further?

Comment: That worked, thanks! I wonder why that isn't mentioned e.g. [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard).

Comment: Unfortunately, there are other problems: vim isn't indenting as usual, and the backspace key has stopped working. I'm sure these could individually be solved as well, but what I really want is for *all* the usual settings to be loaded just as without the `.vimrc` file, except that I also want to enable copy to clipboard. Why should having one's own `.vimrc` overwrite other settings that are not mentioned in the `.vimrc` file?

Comment: it looks like you system vimrc is used if you don't have an own vimrc. delete your vimrc and run the command `:echo $MYVIMRC` copy the echoed file as your vimrc `~/.vimrc` and add the `set clipboard=unnamed` line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no `vimrc`, vim loads a `defaults.vim` file, but once you add a custom `vimrc`, vim stops loading that file. This was introduced in Vim 8.0, and you can get more info by typing `:h defaults.vim` within vim, but here are your options to fix the issue:

SOLUTION 1:

Source the `defaults.vim` file into your `.vimrc` (this is the method mentioned in the vim help files - see `:help defaults.vim`). Just add these lines to the top of your `.vimrc`:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim    
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

SOLUTION 2:

Copy the stuff you like from `defaults.vim` into your own config.
This involves a few steps:

1. Figure out what $VIMRUNTIME is set to by typing `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` inside of vim and hitting enter.
2. Navigate to the directory it returns (for me this was `/usr/local/share/vim/vim80/`) and find the `defaults.vim` file.
3. Copy and paste any of the settings that you want into your own `.vimrc`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic, that's just what I was looking for.